# String Concatenation with Integers

Tags: c++, string, integer, concatenation

`Damage` and `Cost` are integers, but as you can see in the code below I want to concatenate them with a string (if that's the right word). How can I do this?

```
class Weapon : Shopable{
    private:
        int Damage;
    public:
        std::string getDesc() const{
            return getName()+"\t"+Damage+"\t"+Cost;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provide yourself with this template:

```
#include <sstream>

template <class TYPE> std::string Str( const TYPE & t ) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << t;
    return os.str();
}
```

You can then say:

```
return getName() + "\t" + Str( Damage ) + "\t" + Str(Cost);
```

Note this is pretty much equivalent to Boost's `lexical_cast`, and to similar facilities in the upcoming standard. Also note that this function trades performance for convenience and type-safety.

Comment: Is that the only way? I assumed there was some easy built in method I hadn't come across in my searches. In Lua (my primary language) there's just a tostring() function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) as follows:

```
return getName()+"\t"+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(Damage)+
  "\t"+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(Cost);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already accepted @unapersson's answer, but for the record I would do this...

```
std::string getDesc() const
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << getName() << "\t" << Damage << "\t" << Cost;
    return ss.str();
}
```

It only constructs one stream object instead of creating and throwing them away for each conversion, and it looks a bit nicer too.

(This is the C++ way - there's no general 'toString' member like other languages, generally we use string streams or a one-off function like in @unapersson's answer.)